# WiX Service Install with user credentials or LocalSystem depending on UI input

Tags: wix

Below is a section of my .wxs installer file which installed my service. I have a WiX UI dialog where the user can either choose to install the service to run under the `LocalSystem` account or input the credentials of the account they want. The UI has two text boxes (one bound to the `ACCOUNT` property and one to the `PASSWORD` property) and a checkbox that is bound to a property called `USELOCALSYSTEMACCOUNT`.

Individually, these service installers work fine, you can see both `ServiceInstall` sections below. However I want the installer to install the service with the user input credentials if `USELOCALSYSTEMACCOUNT` is not set to 1, or to use the `LocalSystem` account if `USELOCALSYSTEMACCOUNT` is set to 1, but I am unsure how to do this. the `Condition` tag doesn't work within a `ServiceInstall` tag so I'm a bit lost on how to achieve this.

WiX component section below:

```
<Component Id='MainExe' Guid='*'>
  <File Id='MainService' 
        Name='MyService.exe'
        Source='$(var.ServiceRoot2)\SA.MyService.exe'/>
    <ServiceInstall Id='MyService' 
                    Type='ownProcess' 
                    Vital='yes' Name='MyService' 
                    Name='$(var.HumanProductName)' 
                    Description='$(var.ProductDescription)' 
                    Start='demand' 
                    Account='[ACCOUNT]' 
                    Password='[PASSWORD]' 
                    ErrorControl='ignore' 
                    Interactive='no'/>
    <ServiceInstall Id='MyService' 
                    Type='ownProcess' 
                    Vital='yes' 
                    Name='$(var.HumanProductName)'  
                    Description='$(var.ProductDescription)' 
                    Start='demand' 
                    Account='LocalSystem' 
                    ErrorControl='ignore' 
                    Interactive='no'/>
    <ServiceControl Id='MyServiceServiceControl' 
                    Stop='both' 
                    Remove='both' 
                    Name='$(var.HumanProductName)' 
                    Wait='yes'/>
</Component>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to put the condition around the entire component and just have the LocalSystem version and the User specified version. Wix is smart enough to not package the Myservice.exe twice in the installer. Just make sure your condition has "OR Installed" appended to it because I've had issues in the past with conditional components/features not uninstalling because the property they depended on was not set during uninstall. If it is a state of the machine (VersionNT/VersionVT64 which remain constant) then omitting "OR Installed" should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did try something along those lines earlier, but I needed to create two components with different name, which in turn causes more issues as that is referenced elsewhere, for example in the `ComponentRef` section.

Comment: You could put both components (MainExe_LocalService, MainExe_UserService) in a component group and anywhere you were referencing with ComponentRef, you can use ComponentGroupRef. Shouldn't cause any issue as long as you make sure the conditions on both components are mutually exclusive. (will probably give you an ICE warning about the same file in multiple components)

Comment: Thanks very much Brian! That worked like a charm once I followed you suggestion about a `ComponentGroup`, never used them before.